# How to make a table row clickable, highlight it and call partial view with Ajax.actionclick

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

i'm newbie in MVC 3 and i would like to know how to make a clickable table row, highlight it and load a partial view using ajax,  using mvc 3 ajax features. 
At the moment, i use ajax.actionlink to load the partialview.

This seems like pretty much standard, however, i looked all over internet and haven't found anything.

Keep in mind i know how to do this using jquery, but i would like to use mvc 3 ajax features.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC 3 uses jQuery behind the scenes now. You are limited to a basic use of loading into a div with the Ajax helpers -  go outside of that and use jQuery and use the dialog, etc. Since you are familiar with jQuery technical details prob arent required but in that case jQuery ajax calls with jQuery ui is quite a good combination. For other important ajax features in mvc 3 - see unobtrusive javascript features on my blog post at:
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/unobstrusive-javascript-in-mvc-3-helps.html

Comment: Well, that's what I thought, no way of doing it with ajax.actionlink. jQuery it is then. Thanks